# How to write a function that takes parameters and flags in random orders?

Tags: bash, shell, macos

I am new to shell and I was trying to write a custom function that takes regular arguments, as well as parse any flags provided.

```
test_it() {
  flag1="false"
  flag2="false"

  while getopts "ab" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
    a) flag1="true" ;;
    b) flag2="true" ;;
    *) break ;;
    esac
  done
  echo $flag1 $flag2
  shift "$(($OPTIND - 1))"
  echo "Custom param: $1"
}
```

However, this function would only work as I wanted if I supply the custom param after the flags. If I were to supply the custom param before the flags, it doesn't parse the flags.

```
> test_it -ab foo
true true
Custom param: foo
> test_it foo -ab
false false
Custom param: foo
> test_it -a foo -b
true false
Custom param: foo
```

Is there a way in which I can make it so that the flags and params get parsed correctly regardless of order? In other words, it should echo `true true` for both flags in all three of these cases, since they were invoked at some point during the function call?  This should be possible, as I have observed functions like `rsync` to behave that way.

Comment: Use a function name other than `test` -- you're overriding the builtin command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: in a function, before calling `while getopts`, add

```bash
local OPTIND OPTARG
```

That will reset the "counter" to 0 each time.

---

Note also that `while getopts` will stop at the first non-option. If you want `test foo -ab` to work, you need to use [`getopt(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux/getopt.1.en.html) ([`getopt` example script](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-example.bash))

```bash
test_it() {
    local tmp flag1=false flag2=false
    tmp=$(getopt -o 'ab' -n "$FUNCNAME" -- "$@")
    
    local rc=$?
    ((rc == 0)) || return $rc
    
    eval set -- "$tmp"
    
    while true; do
        case "$1" in
            '-a') flag1=true
                  shift
                  ;;
            '-b') flag2=true
                  shift
                  ;;
            '--') shift
                  break
                  ;;
            *)    echo Internal Error >&2
                  return 1
                  ;;
        esac
    done

    declare -p flag1 flag2
    echo "Remaining params:"
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
}
```

```bash
$ test_it foo -a bar -b
declare -- flag1="true"
declare -- flag2="true"
Remaining params:
foo
bar

$ test_it -a quz
declare -- flag1="true"
declare -- flag2="false"
Remaining params:
quz

$ test_it baz -b
declare -- flag1="false"
declare -- flag2="true"
Remaining params:
baz

$ test_it -c
test_it: invalid option -- c

$ test_it baz --ab
test_it: unrecognized option `--ab'
```

Comment: Just a reminder that not all versions of `getopt` support arguments with whitespace in them, the `getopt -o` invocation and the use of `eval set ...` with the output. The util-linux version is the main one that does support them, but it looks like Busybox's version also does (including the `-T` option to test that support). The more traditional ones are meant for `args=$(getopt...); set -- $args` without `eval` (and without quotes), and that has some rather obvious failings.

Comment: And I see the [tag:macos] tag on the question now. The default /usr/bin/getopt on the mac is an old version: I'd recommend installing Homebrew, and then install the bash and gnu-getopt packages.

Comment: @glennjackman hi glenn, thanks for the answer. I am currently figuring out how to get gnu-getopt working, and will try out your answer once I am able to do so.